# Find all groups (including nested groups) a user belongs to in AD

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I apologize if this has been asked before. I searched around for a while and I couldn't find a straightforward solution. Maybe there isn't one, or maybe I am too new at this to even understand a good answer.

I am trying to come up with a script where I can input a user's Account Name and get all of the groups they belong to (including nested groups).

If there is a way to show any tree/inheritance information so I can know how a user is getting a certain group that would be wonderful. Or, if I could search for a specific group in that user's permissions and then get an output with tree/inheritance information when the script finds a match that would be miraculous!

I would post some of the code I've seen but at this point I am kind of confused. I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you!

Comment: What Windows Version are you using ?

Comment: There are multiple versions of Windows in the environment. I don't have direct access to the actual AD servers. But I can run PowerShell commands from a specialized Win Server 2016 Datacenter machine. Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

May this could be helpful:

> GetADUser-Command:
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-user?view=exchange-ps

With -Filter you can filter by most attributes of ADUser

I think you can also filter by permissions